# Duplicate columns from Pandas get_dummies

Tags: pandas

Taken a data set like the following (output from `df.head()`)

```
individual  states
1           Alaska, Hawaii 
2           Hawaii, Alaska
3           Kansas, Iowa, Maryland
4           New Jersey, Newada
5           Newada, New Jersey
```

If I run

```
df['states'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

I am getting the following

```
    Hawaii  Iowa    Maryland    New Jersey  Newada  Alaska  Hawaii  Kansas  New Jersey  Newada
0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
2   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Note the duplicate (repeated) columns. The values differ between multiple column occurences, so I can't just drop them. Where is the problem coming from, how do I do it right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is separator, need `', '`, else get some columns names with spaces, what are different like without, so new columns are created:

```
df1 = df['states'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')

print (df1.columns)
Index([' Alaska', ' Hawaii', ' Iowa', ' Maryland', ' New Jersey', ' Newada',
       'Alaska', 'Hawaii', 'Kansas', 'New Jersey', 'Newada'],
      dtype='object')
```

---

```
print (df1)
    Alaska   Hawaii   Iowa   Maryland   New Jersey   Newada  Alaska  Hawaii  \
0        0        1      0          0            0        0       1       0   
1        1        0      0          0            0        0       0       1   
2        0        0      1          1            0        0       0       0   
3        0        0      0          0            0        1       0       0   
4        0        0      0          0            1        0       0       0   

   Kansas  New Jersey  Newada  
0       0           0       0  
1       0           0       0  
2       1           0       0  
3       0           1       0  
4       0           0       1
```

---

```
df2 = df['states'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
print (df2)
   Alaska  Hawaii  Iowa  Kansas  Maryland  New Jersey  Newada
0       1       1     0       0         0           0       0
1       1       1     0       0         0           0       0
2       0       0     1       1         1           0       0
3       0       0     0       0         0           1       1
4       0       0     0       0         0           1       1
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! I have however used .str.replace(" ","") to remove whitespace instead of putting the whitespace in the separator