# create one-hot encoding for multi-labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

Given the below data stored in a text file:

```
fricative     f, s, S, x, v, z, Z, G, h
nasal       n, m, N
lateral   r, l, j, J
labial      p, b, m, f, v
coronal   s, z, n, d, t, r, l, j, J, S, Z
dorsal      g, k, G, x, N, h
frontal   e, i, I, E, E:, E~, j, J,
```

How can I create a one-hot encoding function that places the individual letters in the first column and in front of each letter there is a one-hot encoding that describes the existing labels:

| **letters** | **fricative** | **nasal** | **lateral** | **labial** | **coronal** | **dorsal** | **frontal** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| f | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| g | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| j | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639104/duplicate-columns-from-pandas-get-dummies), but it possible in a custom function like below:

```
def one_hot_labels(df):
    '''
    - for each line, create a dictionary indicating the presence (1) 
or the absence (0) of every label
    - put the dictionaries in the list and convert it to a data frame
    '''
dict_labels = []
for i in (range(len(df)), leave=False):
    d = dict(zip(range(n_labels), [0]*n_labels))
    ...
    dict_labels.append(d)

    df_labels = pd.DataFrame(dict_labels)
return df_labels
```

Comment: So `fricative` and `f, s, S,...` are the column names?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the reply. I just fixed the table, the column names are `fricative nasal lateral labial coronal dorsal frontal` The first colum is for the letters, so each row is a vector having 1 if column title (ie label) is present, and 0 if column title (label)  is not present. Example row2  `f 1 0 0 1 0 0 1` means that the letter `f` is fricative, labial, and frontal.

Answer (score 2):

Try `.str.get_dummies()`:

```
# assuming the two columns are named `text` and `labels`
(df['letters'].str.replace(' ','')   # remove all spaces
    .str.get_dummies(',')            # get the dummies
    .set_index(df['text'])           # assign the associated text
    .T                               # transpose to match the requirement
)
```

This is what you get:

```
text  fricative  nasal  lateral  labial  coronal  dorsal  frontal
E             0      0        0       0        0       0        1
E:            0      0        0       0        0       0        1
E~            0      0        0       0        0       0        1
G             1      0        0       0        0       1        0
I             0      0        0       0        0       0        1
J             0      0        1       0        1       0        1
N             0      1        0       0        0       1        0
S             1      0        0       0        1       0        0
Z             1      0        0       0        1       0        0
b             0      0        0       1        0       0        0
d             0      0        0       0        1       0        0
e             0      0        0       0        0       0        1
f             1      0        0       1        0       0        0
g             0      0        0       0        0       1        0
h             1      0        0       0        0       1        0
i             0      0        0       0        0       0        1
j             0      0        1       0        1       0        1
k             0      0        0       0        0       1        0
l             0      0        1       0        1       0        0
m             0      1        0       1        0       0        0
n             0      1        0       0        1       0        0
p             0      0        0       1        0       0        0
r             0      0        1       0        1       0        0
s             1      0        0       0        1       0        0
t             0      0        0       0        1       0        0
v             1      0        0       1        0       0        0
x             1      0        0       0        0       1        0
z             1      0        0       0        1       0        0
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but as mentioned in the question post, the `get_dummies` doesn't seem to work. Example the letter `f` should have a vector like this `1 0 0 1 0 0 1` but it's giving `1 0 0 1 0 0 0`.. That's why I'd like to use a custom function with a for loop and the construct the dictionary Thanks again

Comment: Why would `frontal` has `f` in it? You data does not have it? Re *each letter should be mentioned once*, where do you see duplicates?

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the values into a `set` and a `dict` and then construct a `DataFrame` with the required conditions -

```
input_str = io.StringIO('''fricative     f, s, S, x, v, z, Z, G, h
nasal       n, m, N
lateral   r, l, j, J
labial      p, b, m, f, v
coronal   s, z, n, d, t, r, l, j, J, S, Z
dorsal      g, k, G, x, N, h
frontal   e, i, I, E, E:, E~, j, J''')

category_to_letters = dict()
letters = set()

for input in input_str:
    _category, *_letters = input.strip().split()
    _letters = set(_letter.split(',')[0] for _letter in _letters if _letter.split(',')[0].strip())
    category_to_letters[_category] = _letters
    letters = letters.union(set(_letters))

df = pd.DataFrame({}, index=letters, columns=category_to_letters.keys())
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[:, col] = df.index.isin(category_to_letters[col])
```

Comment: Thank you. The text file is actually a lot bigger, and therefore, it's better to read from the txt using a function `def one_hot_encoding(fname): ... Return one_hot_encoding`.